# Программа открывает окно, заголовком которого является командная строка

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Осваиваю свои первые шаги в WinApi. На пути лаба в условии которой сказано: `Программа открывает окно, заголовком которого является командная строка.` Что-то я совершенно не представляю, как командная строка должна оказаться в моем заголовке.

Comment: Вы не знаете как задать заголовок окна в Windows?

Comment: Знаю. Но не совсем понял условия. Вот конкретно прям по картинке, на заголовке (1) должна быть командная строка? 
http://dims.karelia.ru/win32/appwnd.gif

Comment: **окно, заголовком которого является командная строка**. Разве можно понять вот эти слова как-то по-другому?

Comment: Так почему же они не написали: заголовком которого является "командная строка". Я то понял это всё в буквальном смысле, что мне каким то образом туда надо запихнуть рабочую командную строку, в которою я могу что-то ввести...

Comment: Командная строка - это (если не вдаваться в системнозависимые подробности) имя запускаемой программы и её аргументы. Безо всяких кавычек.

Comment: Так я если честно и не понял чего от меня хотят. Что бы я сделал программу в заголовке которой написано "Командная строка" или что бы в этом заголовке были какие-то сведения из самой программы? Например у меня программа выводит координаты окна, и они должны дублировать в сам заголовок? Я совсем запутался

Comment: Вообще я думаю вам лучше спросить того, кто ставит такие задачи

Comment: Бррр.. Как всё запутанно :( Неужели я спросил какую-то сложную вещь.

Comment: Я не знаю, как ещё можно понять постановку задачи :) Вы знаете что такое командная строка программы?

Comment: Не запутано, просто термин "команданая строка" не является однозначным.

Comment: Да знаю. Но не должна же у меня быть командная строка cmd.exe в заголовке файла в конец то концов)

Comment: "**термин "команданая строка" не является однозначным**" - для программиста или для секретарши?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз речь про WinAPI, то под командной строкой скорей всего подразумевается командая строка, с которой запустили приложение (то что было передано в CreateProcess). Ее можно получить с помощью функции `::GetCommandLineW()`.

Так что "Программа открывает окно, заголовком которого является командная строка" выглядит как-то так:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma comment(linker, "/entry:mainCRTStartup")
int main() {
    ::MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"^_^", ::GetCommandLineW(), MB_OK);
}
```

Comment: Вооот! скорее всего это как раз то, что и имелось ввиду. Спасибо!

Comment: Вам о том, что такое "командная строка" говорилось в первых же комментариях :)

Comment: Значит я не правильно понял изначально) Я ещё новичок совсем.